# How to set base url for rest in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm trying to to mix mvc and rest in a single spring boot project.

I want to set base path for all rest controllers (eg. example.com/api)
in a single place (I don't want annotate each controller with `@RequestMapping('api/products')`, instead, just `@RequestMapping('/products')`.

Mvc controllers should be accessible by example.com/whatever

Is it possible?

(I don't use spring data rest, just spring mvc)

Comment: take a look at this http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-pattern-comparison

Comment: server.servlet.contextPath=/api

Comment: spring boot version 2.1.4.RELEASE, spring.mvc.servlet.path=/api and server.servlet.context-path=/api , both works

Comment: server.servlet.context-path=/api solution is for APPLICATION , not for only REST. It is valid for SOAP services also. If you want to sperate your SOAP and REST services path, you should use @RequestMapping('api/...')... https://medium.com/@bm.celalkartal/how-to-create-rest-and-soap-services-in-same-spring-boot-application-9054d69767a6

Answer (score 172, accepted):

With Spring Boot 1.2+ (<2.0) all it takes is a single property in application.properties:

```
spring.data.rest.basePath=/api
```

ref link : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#getting-started.changing-base-uri

For 2.x, use

```
server.servlet.context-path=/api
```

Comment: This is the exact answer that thorinkor gave.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work for me in Spring Boot version v1.5.7.RELEASE. The other answer server.contextPath=/api worked

Comment: @Suroj That solution works only with RepositoryRestController annotated controllers, not with RestController...

Comment: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1211 This Jira Ticket mentions it being "spring.data.rest.base-path for Spring Boot 2.0.0". Sadly, both don't work for me.

Comment: for SB 2+ it's server.servlet.context-path=/url

Comment: spring boot version 2.1.4.RELEASE, spring.mvc.servlet.path=/api and server.servlet.context-path=/api , both works

Comment: I believe this answer is correct for the REST services automatically generated by Spring Data REST.  This isn't the same thing as for REST services you write yourself using @RestController and Spring MVC.

Comment: I don't understand how this answer got accepted or got so many up-votes. As mentioned by several other comments, this answer does not work (for @RestController) and is equivalent to another answer given almost 6 months before.

Comment: `server.servlet.context-path=/api` sets the base path for all the requests. If you want to serve static files (HTML, CSS Javascript) from `/` while all REST API endpoints should be on `/api`, this won't work, because also the static HTML and other files will be served from `/api`. See other responses below!

Comment: What's the difference between `spring.mvc.servlet.path` and `server.servlet.context-path` (for Boot 2)?

Answer (score 104):

A bit late but the same question brought me here before reaching the answer so I post it here.
Create (if you still don't have it) an application.properties and add

```
server.contextPath=/api
```

So in the previous example if you have a RestController with `@RequestMapping("/test")` you will access it like `localhost:8080/api/test/{your_rest_method}`

question source: [how do i choose the url for my spring boot webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452072/how-do-i-choose-the-url-for-my-spring-boot-webapp)

Comment: How do you enforce this to only work with RestControllers and access the  normal Controllers without the "/api"

Comment: @Stoan I found solution, check my answer :-)

Comment: Don't do this! See thorinkor's answer.

Comment: Thorinkor's answer is specifically for Spring Data REST.

Comment: server.contextPath is now deprecated, use server.servlet.context-path instead

Answer (score 62):

For spring boot framework version `2.0.4.RELEASE+`. Add this line to `application.properties`

```
server.servlet.context-path=/api
```

Comment: This also does affect the public folder :-(

Comment: this is the correct answer for Spring boot 2+. `spring.data.rest.basePath` does not work for Spring boot 2

Comment: server.servlet.context-path works for spring boot 2

Answer (score 42):

Try using a PathMatchConfigurer (Spring Boot 2.x):

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer  {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.addPathPrefix("api", HandlerTypePredicate.forAnnotation(RestController.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for!
This allows you to set a context path element for all RestControllers configured through this WebMvcConfig, similar to what spring.data.rest.base-path does.

Comment: Your answer is spot on @HaraldWendel :+1:  You could improve upon it some more by expanding upon it a bit, like explaining what your code does exactly (as I've tried to do in my comment) and/or maybe link to some javadoc or documentation that describes this usage.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me as I'm using controller interfaces

Comment: This is the only right answer. It should be flagged as THE ANSWER.

Comment: Worked flawlessly!

Answer (score 32):

I couldn't believe how complicate the answer to this seemingly simple question is. Here are some references:

- [Spring JIRA Ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13882)
- [Another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801351/how-to-configure-a-default-restcontroller-uri-prefix-for-all-controllers)
- [Yet another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927937/how-to-set-base-url-for-rest-in-spring-boot)
- [Very nice GitRepository that showcases the problem](https://github.com/mike-boddin/spring-data-rest-example)

There are many differnt things to consider:

1. By setting`server.context-path=/api` in `application.properties` you can configure a prefix for *everything*.(Its server.context-path   not server.contextPath !)
2. Spring Data controllers annotated with @RepositoryRestController that expose a repository as rest endpoint will use the environment variable `spring.data.rest.base-path` in `application.properties`.  But plain `@RestController` won't take this into account. According to the [spring data rest documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers) there is an annotation `@BasePathAwareController` that you can use for that.  But I do have problems in connection with Spring-security when I try to secure such a controller. It is not found anymore.

Another workaround is a simple trick. You cannot prefix a static String in an annotation, but you can use expressions like this:

```
@RestController
public class PingController {

  /**
   * Simple is alive test
   * @return <pre>{"Hello":"World"}</pre>
   */
  @RequestMapping("${spring.data.rest.base-path}/_ping")
  public String isAlive() {
    return "{\"Hello\":\"World\"}";
  }
}
```

Comment: How would you put in into Annotation?

Comment: meh, then you always have to remember to add this prefix each time you create a new controller

Answer (score 28):

Since this is the first google hit for the problem and I assume more people will search for this. There is a new option since Spring Boot '1.4.0'.
It is now possible to define a custom *RequestMappingHandlerMapping* that allows to define a different path for classes annotated with *@RestController*

A different version with custom annotations that combines *@RestController* with *@RequestMapping* can be found at this [blog post](https://mhdevelopment.wordpress.com/2016/10/03/spring-restcontroller-specific-basepath/)

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcRegistrationsAdapter webMvcRegistrationsHandlerMapping() {
        return new WebMvcRegistrationsAdapter() {
            @Override
            public RequestMappingHandlerMapping getRequestMappingHandlerMapping() {
                return new RequestMappingHandlerMapping() {
                    private final static String API_BASE_PATH = "api";

                    @Override
                    protected void registerHandlerMethod(Object handler, Method method, RequestMappingInfo mapping) {
                        Class<?> beanType = method.getDeclaringClass();
                        if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(beanType, RestController.class) != null) {
                            PatternsRequestCondition apiPattern = new PatternsRequestCondition(API_BASE_PATH)
                                    .combine(mapping.getPatternsCondition());

                            mapping = new RequestMappingInfo(mapping.getName(), apiPattern,
                                    mapping.getMethodsCondition(), mapping.getParamsCondition(),
                                    mapping.getHeadersCondition(), mapping.getConsumesCondition(),
                                    mapping.getProducesCondition(), mapping.getCustomCondition());
                        }

                        super.registerHandlerMethod(handler, method, mapping);
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: In Spring Boot 2.0.0+, work off the WebMvcRegistrations interface directly. WebMvcRegistrationsAdapter was removed in favor of adding default methods to the interface.

Answer (score 24):

You can create a custom annotation for your controllers:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public @interface MyRestController {
}
```

Use it instead of the usual @RestController on your controller classes and annotate methods with @RequestMapping.

Just tested - works in Spring 4.2!

Comment: Thank you. I've tried this. But now I have to annotate each method with @RequestMapping("/products"),  @RequestMapping("/products/{id}"). Instead I need annotate Controller with @RequestMapping("/products") and methods with @RequestMapping, @RequestMapping("/:id"). And products controller should be accesable at api/products (e.g. set api prefix in a single place)

Comment: In that case, no, there is no solution out of the box, AFAIK. You can try implementing your own `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`. Spring Data REST has a mapper similar to what you need - `BasePathAwareHandlerMapping`.

Comment: @moreo, did you find a proper solution? I'd be happy if you could post it as a response. i have the same requirement here.

Comment: @fischermatte, No, I didn't find exactly what I wanted, I place @RequestMapping("/api/products") or @RequestMapping("/api/users")  before each controller class and then, before method just another @RequestMapping("/{id}").  But I don't think this is a big issue, if I want to change "api" to something, I will just change it in the beginning of each class.

Comment: @IlyaNovoseltsev There is a solution, see my answer :-)

Comment: tried a few configuration bean approaches and others but in the end this is the cleanest a most usable solution for me. thanks

Comment: This is what i had been looking for, Thanks

Comment: thats good. the other solutions were more complex and we dont need to

Answer (score 17):

I did some research on the differences of spring properties mentioned in this thread. Here are my findings if anybody is wondering.

### spring.data.rest.basePath Property

```
spring.data.rest.basePath=/api
```

This property is specifically for **Spring Data Rest** projects. It won't work in a usual Spring MVC projects.

To change the context path in MVC projects, you can use those two properties mentioned below. Let me mention the differences too.

### server.servlet.context-path Property

```
server.servlet.context-path=/api
```

This one sets the context path on your web servelet. This property perfectly works fine in both spring mvc and spring data rest projects. **But,** the differnce is the request url will be filter out before reaching spring interceptors. So it will respond with HTML on bad request. Not Spring's or your own custom JSON response (in @ResponseBodyAdvice annotated class) defined. To overcome that, you should use this property below.

### spring.mvc.servlet.path Property

```
spring.mvc.servlet.path=/api
```

This will filter the request URL in spring mvc interceptors and will respond default/your custom JSON response if you invoke a bad request.

### Conclusion:

So as the OP's question, I would suggest that he should use **spring.mvc.servlet.path** to change the context path.

Answer (score 14):

For Boot 2.0.0+ this works for me: server.servlet.context-path = /api

Comment: That put everything under /api it seems, not only @RestController mappers. But thanks anyway. Your information is still useful.

Answer (score 10):

I found a clean solution, which affects only rest controllers.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean restApi() {
        XmlWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.setParent(context);
        applicationContext.setConfigLocation("classpath:/META-INF/rest.xml");

        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();
        dispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

        ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet, "/rest/*");
        servletRegistrationBean.setName("restApi");

        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }

    static public void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApp.class,args);
    }
}
```

Spring boot will register two dispatcher servlets - default `dispatcherServlet` for controllers, and `restApi` dispatcher for `@RestControllers` defined in `rest.xml`:

```
2016-06-07 09:06:16.205  INFO 17270 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'restApi' to [/rest/*]
2016-06-07 09:06:16.206  INFO 17270 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
```

The example `rest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.example.web.rest"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Configure to plugin JSON as request and response in method handler -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
    <bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

But, you're **not limited to**:

- use `XmlWebApplicationContext`, you may use any else context type available, ie. `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext`, `GenericWebApplicationContext`, `GroovyWebApplicationContext`, ...
- define `jsonMessageConverter`, `messageConverters` beans in rest context, they may be defined in parent context

Comment: Is it possible to do this programmatically without use of the xml?

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh Yes. It's possible to do it programmatically. There are many ways to setup spring context. In the example, I have shown how to create child context for REST API handling. Just learn how to setup context within Java, and then combine such knowledge with knowledge in this answer. That's called programming.

Answer (score 6):

I might be a bit late, BUT... I believe it is the best solution. Set it up in your application.yml (or similar config file):

```
spring:
    data:
        rest:
            basePath: /api
```

As I can remember that's it - all of your repositories will be exposed beneath this URI.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit or point to a releavant documentation?

Comment: Relevant docs are at http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_changing_the_base_uri.

Comment: the environemnt variable  `spring.data.rest.base-path`  only affects spring-data-rest and spring-hateoas.  Plain @RestController  will still sit at the root!

Comment: @Robert of course, but I think currently in most cases You will use Spring Data REST Repositories instead of doing the controllers on your own.

Comment: @thorinkor based on what are you saying that in most cases people will build Spring Data REST repositories? And the OP is clearly saying he has rest controllers...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisBeauchef I think Spring Data REST gives a great oportunity to use it "out of the box" in many cases, instead of writing custom services, repositories and controllers. I've got a feeling this generally is a SpringBoot approach - first configure, than code.

Comment: I think it will only work if you are using SpringDataRest.

Comment: Why colons, as opposed to periods? (The documentation uses periods.)

Answer (score 5):

You can create a base class with `@RequestMapping("rest")` annotations and extend all you other classes with this base class.

```
@RequestMapping("rest")
public abstract class BaseController {}
```

Now all classes that extend this base class will be accessible at `rest/**`.

Comment: This is not correct answer, the user is referring to Controller annotation. If you extend an abstract class with a RequestMapping annotation, and the new class has a RequestMapping too, this last will override the first one, it will not concatenate the two.

Comment: Are you aware that annotations are not inherited in java unless it has inherited meta annotation? Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21409651. And @RequestMapping does not seem to have that: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html

Answer (score 2):

With spring-boot 2.x you can configure in application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.servlet.path=/api
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who use YAML configuration(application.yaml).

**Note**: this works only for `Spring Boot 2.x.x`

```
server:
  servlet:
    contextPath: /api
```

If you are still using `Spring Boot 1.x`

```
server:
  contextPath: /api
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom annotation for your controllers:

Use it instead of the usual @RestController on your controller classes and annotate methods with @RequestMapping.

Works fine in Spring 4.2!

Answer (score 1):

`server.servlet.context-path=/api` would be the solution I guess. I had the same issue and this got me solved. I used server.context-path. However, that seemed to be deprecated and I found that `server.servlet.context-path` solves the issue now. Another workaround I found was adding a base tag to my front end (H5) pages. I hope this helps someone out there.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

For Spring WebFlux the approach is similar to Harald's, but with the obvious WebFlux configuration set up:

```
@Configuration
public class WebFluxConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer  {

   @Override
   public void configurePathMatching(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
       configurer.addPathPrefix("/api", HandlerTypePredicate.forAnnotation(RestController.class));
   }
}
```

And for Kotlin it's:

```
@Configuration
class WebFluxConfig : WebFluxConfigurer {
    override fun configurePathMatching(configurer: PathMatchConfigurer) {
       configurer.addPathPrefix("/api", HandlerTypePredicate.forAnnotation(RestController::class.java))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution applies if:

1. You want to prefix `RestController` but not `Controller`.
2. You are not using Spring Data Rest.

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

   @Override
   protected RequestMappingHandlerMapping createRequestMappingHandlerMapping() {
       return new ApiAwareRequestMappingHandlerMapping();
   }

   private static class ApiAwareRequestMappingHandlerMapping extends RequestMappingHandlerMapping {

       private static final String API_PATH_PREFIX = "api";

       @Override
       protected void registerHandlerMethod(Object handler, Method method, RequestMappingInfo mapping) {
           Class<?> beanType = method.getDeclaringClass();
           if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(beanType, RestController.class) != null) {
               PatternsRequestCondition apiPattern = new PatternsRequestCondition(API_PATH_PREFIX)
                       .combine(mapping.getPatternsCondition());

               mapping = new RequestMappingInfo(mapping.getName(), apiPattern, mapping.getMethodsCondition(),
                       mapping.getParamsCondition(), mapping.getHeadersCondition(), mapping.getConsumesCondition(),
                       mapping.getProducesCondition(), mapping.getCustomCondition());
           }
           super.registerHandlerMethod(handler, method, mapping);
       }
   }
   ```

   }

This is similar to the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39907655/2860319) posted by mh-dev, but I think this is a little cleaner and this should be supported on any version of Spring Boot 1.4.0+, including 2.0.0+.

Comment: If i'm using Pageable in my RestControler, api/something gives me No primary or default constructor found for interface org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable

Answer (score 0):

Per Spring Data REST [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#getting-started.changing-base-uri), if using *application.properties*, use this property to set your base path:

```
spring.data.rest.basePath=/api
```

But note that Spring [uses](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Configuration-Binding#relaxed-binding) [relaxed binding](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Relaxed-Binding-2.0), so this variation can be used:

```
spring.data.rest.base-path=/api
```

... or this one if you prefer:

```
spring.data.rest.base_path=/api
```

If using *application.yml*, you would use colons for key separators:

```
spring:
  data:
    rest:
      basePath: /api
```

(For reference, a related [ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1211) was created in March 2018 to clarify the docs.)

Answer (score -2):

worked    server.contextPath=/path