# Setting Spring REST controllers base url without changing the static resources base url

Tags: spring

I have a spring boot application with bunch of rest controllers (@RestController).

I use the following property in `application.properties` file to set the base url:

`server.context-path=api`

This property changes the base url for my static resources, too. I don't want them to change, how can I do that?

**Note1**
Why I want to do that? I want to serve a single page application (react app) on my server, and I want most of my requests made to `/api/**` to be authorized. I want all other GET requests to be handled by the react router. This is why I don't want the base URL for my static resources to change.

Comment: with version 1.2+ of spring boot you can use: 
  spring.data.rest.basePath=/api

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should not use this property as it changes the context path for the whole application.

Why not simply specify `/api/yourResource` in the `RequestMapping` annotation such as :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/oneController")
public class OneController { ... }
```

.....

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/anotherController")
public class AnotherController { ... }
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do this as programmatically as possible, and control it in a one central point.

Answer (score 11):

You can use

```
spring.data.rest.base-path=/api
```

in your application properties with

```
@BasePathAwareController
```

on your controller class.

When you use

```
server.context-path=ctx
```

the context path applies to the whole application including

- static resources
- end points created with `@Controller`
- end points created with `@RestController`
- end points created with `@BasePathAwareContoller`
- end points created with `@RepositoryRestController`
- end points created with `@RepositoryRestResource`

When you use

```
spring.data.rest.base-path=/api
```

the prefix applies to

- end points created with `@BasePathAwareContoller`
- end points created with `@RepositoryRestController`
- end points created with `@RepositoryRestResource`

And you can use both

```
server.context-path=ctx
spring.data.rest.base-path=/api
```

to apply a prefix like `/ctx/api/`

Comment: I don't think it's that straight. Look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47428518/spring-data-rest-base-path-makes-two-endpoints-available/47447580?noredirect=1#comment81884619_47447580

Comment: My suggestion/idea was to use spring.data.rest.base-path in properties file and @BasePathAwareContoller in controllers (in place of @Controller/@RestController). I use it with spring boot 1.5.8.RELEASE, and it works fine.

Comment: that's right, but there will be a shadow endpoint available at the URL without the path, too.

Comment: I don't see any shadow endpoints in my environment. I am using spring boot 1.5.8.RELEASE.

Comment: Thanks. You're my hero. No one suggested to annotate the controller class with BasePathAwareController

Answer (score 3):

You can define your path as a property in the .properties file and read it using the @Value annotation

example

in the application.properties

```
common.basepath = /test
```

in the controller use

```
@RequestMapping(@Value("${common.basepath}"))
```

Comment: I doubt if this works. AFAIK, request mapping value needs to be a constant, not a derived value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@RequestMapping(ControllerConstant.BASE_API_URL + "/audit")
```

where:

```
public class ControllerConstant {
    public static final String BASE_API_URL = "/whatever/api/v1";
}
```

This way the base URL is centralized in `ControllerConstant.BASE_API_URL`.

I hope this helps.