# The right way to define an API's base path in Api Connect

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-cloud, microservices, apiconnect

**Problem:**

I have two micro services (in Spring Boot) published in [Bluemix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluemix)'s Api Connect. I want to assign a base path to each one so that we have a way to separate them. I.E.:

Path to API 1: `https://api.us.apiconnect.ibmcloud.com/[organization]/[catalog]/api1/[endpoint-of-api1]`
Path to API 2: `https://api.us.apiconnect.ibmcloud.com/[organization]/[catalog]/api2/[endpoint-of-api2]`

---

**My solution:**

Assign a context path to each Api in their **application.yml** file:

```
server:
  contextPath: /api1
```

---

Even though this works, it doesn't seem right to have a base path for the entire server, when the microservice shouldn't be aware of its external context (the reason for a base path is exclusively to have a separation in Api Connect)

Any ideas?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927937/how-to-set-base-url-for-rest-in-spring-boot

Comment: @RobertoParedes: Did the above SO question help solve your issue, or do you still need help?

Comment: @JoshuaAlger Nope, this is actually how I have it now. My question was if there is a better way. Like if Api Connect can configure this instead of having to set it in the app configuration

Comment: @RobertoParedes: I added an answer below to show a better way

Comment: @JoshuaAlger nice! I'm gonna try that solution. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the API Designer you can edit the Base Path and the specific API Paths:

**Base Path:**
[image: Edit Base Path]

**API Paths**
[image: Edit API Path]

To get to these Design settings complete the following steps:

1. In your API Connect service, click the **Drafts** section in the Navigation pane and then click the **APIs** tab:

[image: API Manager]

2. Click the corresponding API you want to edit and the API Designer will be displayed. Here you can edit the Base Path and API Paths as seen in the sections below:

[image: API Designer]

For more information, please see the following documentation 
[Defining Paths for a REST API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMNED_5.0.0/com.ibm.apic.toolkit.doc/task_APIonPrem_defineapiresources.html).