# Changing of Spring Data REST base path doesn't involve custom controllers

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I have Spring Boot app and the following Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/orders/{id}")
@ExposesResourceFor(Payment.class)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PaymentController {
    ...
}
```

When I change

```
spring.data.rest.base-path=/api
```

then Controller reacts to requests without /api base path

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{ \"number\": \"1234123412341234\" }" http://localhost:8080/orders/1/payment
```

i.e. not http://localhost:8080/**api**/orders/1/payment

If I want to have /api base path, this would mean updating controller mapping to `@RequestMapping("/api/orders/{id}")` which is not desirable because I hardcode configuration into code.

Is there any solution to this problem?
Thanks

Comment: That property is for Spring Data Rest controllers. Your controller is a standard Spring MVC constroller. See here for further discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927937/how-to-set-base-url-for-rest-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make your custom controllers aware of the base path configured you have to annotate them with `@RepositoryRestController` instead of `@Controller`

Answer (score 4):

And some remark:

Do NOT use class-level @RequestMapping annotation if you use @RepositoryRestController annotation.

Otherwise your controller methods could be mapped twice !

First by RequestMappingHandlerMapping WITHOUT the basePath, then by the RepositoryRestHandlerAdapter WITH the basePath