# Set base path for swagger.ui.html

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

Is there any way to move the Swagger 2 content to another base URL?

I have seen "[how to do friendly base url for swagger 2.8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49924266/how-to-do-friendly-base-url-for-swagger-2-8-0)" as well as this kind of workaround:

```java
@RequestMapping("/swagger")
public String greeting() {
    return "redirect:/swagger-ui.html";
}
```

**The problem:**

> This is not possible in my case!

My server hosts two web applications and a REST api which is why I have this monster here:

```java
@Controller
public class ForwardController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/sitemap.xml", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String redirectSitemapXml(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "forward:/a/web/assets/sitemap.xml";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/robots.txt", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String redirectRobotTxt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "forward:/a/web/assets/robots.txt";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String redirectRoot(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "forward:/a/web/index.html";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/a/**/{path:[^.]*}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String redirectClients(HttpServletRequest request) {

        String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();

        if (requestURI.startsWith("/a/admin/")) {
            return "forward:/a/admin/index.html";
        }

        return "forward:/a/web/index.html";
    }

}
```

This goes along with Spring Security settings for this setup.

I need swagger to be available under `/a/swagger-ui.html`, but is this possible?

---

The following cannot work either under my `ForwardController`:

- [How to change Swagger-ui URL prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50712519/how-to-change-swagger-ui-url-prefix)

Comment: Did you tried other solutions in link as `SwaggerWebFilter` or `RouterFunction`?

Comment: @user7294900 I cannot find those terms. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Are you using Spring MVC or WebFlux?

Comment: just wondering: every _forward_ starts with _/a/..._ and you want to access swagger via _/a/swagger-ui.html_ Why not setup your context-path to _/a_ ? ```server.servlet.context-path=/a```

Comment: @DirkDeyne Wouldn't hat move *all* my endpoints to `/a`? There is also a REST API which I serve under `/r/api`.

Comment: @displayname yes it would, so that won't work. Assumed, based on your controller there are only /a/... endpoints.

Comment: Does this answer to your question: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/408 ? `Multiple basPaths is not allowed in Swagger. You can use / as your basePath (or don't specify it) (...)`