# How to add additional text in annotation parameter value

Tags: spring-boot, rest, kotlin, annotations

I want to create a **StudentApiController** annotation for RequestMapping. It needs to add auto prefix for the RequestMapping.

**Example usage 1:**

```
@StudentApiController(value="/payment")
class PaymentEndpoint
```

mapping value needs to be **"/student/payment"**

**Example usage 2:**

```
@StudentApiController(value="/exam")
class ExamEndpoint
```

mapping value needs to be **"/student/exam"**

**This is my code:**

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@RequestMapping
annotation class StudentApiController(
    val value: String = "",
    @get:AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping::class, attribute = "value")
    val aliasValue: String = "/student" + value
)
```

I am getting this error:
Default value of annotation parameter must be a compile-time constant

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting all your endpoints to start with /student?
If yes then you can use `spring.mvc.servlet.path=/student` or `server.servlet.context-path=/student` property in your application.properties.

If not then may be you can add logic in interceptor to prefix annotation value provided through your annotation. I haven't tried this for prefixing something in preHandle(), but I have tried it for postHandle() and it works.

[Refer this link](https://blog.codeleak.pl/2013/11/thymeleaf-template-layouts-in-spring.html) it appends thymeleaf's custom layout using custom annotation through interceptor. You can implement same logic for your requirement.

**Edit 1** 
You may refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927937/how-to-set-base-url-for-rest-in-spring-boot) which provides another approach/es to handle your requirement.